# How to make transition in Numpy, python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new to python and I need some help in getting this task done.
How can I implement following matrix in python, using numPy? 
9 x 5 matrix F where each column of F is [1.....9]^T .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[i]*5 for i in range(1, 10)])
```

This basically creates a matrix whose first row is filled with 1s, second row with 2s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1d array:

```
In [25]: np.arange(1,10)                                                                       
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Make a 2d column vector:

```
In [26]: np.arange(1,10)[:,None]                                                               
Out[26]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Use `repeat` method to replicate the columns:

```
In [27]: np.arange(1,10)[:,None].repeat(5,1)                                                   
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```